# Paypal API - How does one pass a description for transactions?

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, payment-gateway, paypal-nvp

I have to pass the description of a payment being made via the Paypal API. This is for a membership dues payment, so I only need to pass a one line description that will be the same for all transactions.

Right now my API calls look as follows:

```
$paypal->setNVP("RETURNURL", "http://www.example.com/actPayDuesConfirm.php");
$paypal->setNVP("CURRENCYCODE", "CAD");
$paypal->setNVP("AMT", number_format($fltTotal, 2));

$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0", "Member Dues Payment");
$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0", number_format($fltTotal, 2));
$paypal->setNVP("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0", 1);

$paypal->setNVP("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC", "Member Dues Payment");
$paypal->setNVP("ITEMAMT", number_format($fltTotal, 2));

$custom = number_format($fltTotal, 2) . "^" . $capTotal . "^" . $cscTotal .     "^" . $capID;
$paypal->setNVP("CUSTOM", $custom);
$paypal->getResponse();
```

I would expect that the description attached to each transaction would be "Member Dues Payment". This is not the case though. Rather all transactions get logged into the Paypal account with no description at all.

Any ideas?